# can't connect to database with php (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect to mysql database with php. The codes are:

---

**index.php**

```
  <button>
    <a href='insert.php'>insert.php geçiş yap</a>
  </button>

 <?php 

  require_once 'baglan.php';
  if(!isset($_GET['sayfa'])){
    $_GET['sayfa'] = 'index';
  }

  switch ($_GET['sayfa']) {
    case 'insert':
      require_once 'insert.php';
      break;
  }

 ?>
```

---

**baglan.php**

```
<?php
try{
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ornek_veritabani','root','');  
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e -> getMessage();
};

?>
```

---

**insert.php**

```
<?php 
  echo 'insert.php';
  $sorgu = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO deneme SET
  ad = ?,
  soyad = ?,
  yas = ?,
  memleket = ?');
  $ekle = $sorgu->execute([
    'php ad','php soyad', 10, 'php memleket'
  ]);

  if($ekle){
    echo 'verileriniz eklendi...';
  } else{
    print_r($sorgu->errorInfo());
  }

?>
```

Problem in insert.php document. Returns error. It gives the following error:

> insert.php
>   Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\insert.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in >C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\insert.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in >C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\insert.php on line 3

Comment: The link in your button is pointing to the wrong file, the one that does not have a database connection included. You probably want to link to `index.php` or require the database file in your insert script.

Comment: please -> ```require_once 'baglan.php';```